# how to cast var to long array?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

The following method returns array of long. But when i run it , get error :

> specified cast is not valid.

```
public long[] GetLastMonthConsume(long metid)
{

   var lastconsume = (from itm in db.tblMonthConsumes
                            where itm.MetID_FK == metid && itm.MonthConsumeDate ==
                                (from itm2 in db.tblMonthConsumes
                                 where itm2.MeterID_FK == metid
                                 select itm2.MonthConsumeDate).Max()
                            select new
                            {
                                itm.MonthConsumeTotal,
                                itm.MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour
                            }).ToList();

    return lastconsume.Cast<long>().ToArray();
}
```

This error occurs in:

```
return lastconsume.Cast<long>().ToArray();
```

Data type of (MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour,MonthConsumeTotal) are long.

This cast is wrong? how to get output of query and cast to array of long???

Comment: Your query selecting an anonymous type containing 2 properties `MonthConsumeTotal` and `MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour`. How do you expect to cast that to an array of `long`? - you need to select just one property and that property needs to be typeof `long`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I want to select two property in one query. how ?

Comment: You are selecting 2 properties, but you cant return it as `long[]`. Not clear exactly how you use the data, but you can create a model containing 2 properties `long MonthConsumeTotal` and `long MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour`, and use `select new yourModel { ..}` and `return IEnumerable<yourModel>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to return 2d array.

```
public long[][] GetLastMonthConsume(long metid)
{

   var lastconsume = (from itm in db.tblMonthConsumes
                            where itm.MetID_FK == metid && itm.MonthConsumeDate ==
                                (from itm2 in db.tblMonthConsumes
                                 where itm2.MeterID_FK == metid
                                 select itm2.MonthConsumeDate).Max()
                            select new
                            {
                               total = (itm.MonthConsumeTotal!= null && itm.MonthConsumeTotal.HasValue) ? itm.MonthConsumeTotal.Value : 0,
                               hour = (itm.MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour!= null && itm.MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour.HasValue) ? itm.MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour.Value : 0
                            }).ToList();

    return lastconsume.Select(t => new long[] {t.total , t.hour }).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I use this code but show error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'long?[][]' to 'long[][]'

Comment: Now i get error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'long?[]' to 'long[] for two (total and hour)

Comment: Check update.. MonthConsumeTotal and MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour are nullable so you will need to check if it has value and take value else take 0

Answer (score 0):

The `lastConsume` is a list of object of anonymous type as you used:

```
select new
{
   itm.MonthConsumeTotal,
   itm.MonthConsumeTotalFuncHour
}
```

Now you are trying to cast it into long which obviously not compatible. Hence, compiler showing error.

You will have to change method signature if you wish to return list of item with two long numbers.